# C# Open a new form while waiting for a response from a server

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to send a Post request to a server and while I'm waiting for the server to respond, I would like a "Please wait" window to pop up with the option to cancel the request. I have tried running the request from an async method and then opening up the window but the rest of my program keeps running. I need the program to call to the server, pop up with the please wait window, and then wait until the I get the response or the cancel button is pressed.

Any help or advice on what I need to do would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Honestly I've just been messing around with it trying a bunch of things that I'm sure I'm using incorrectly. I tried creating a new Thread() and running it from there, I've tried making it a task and running task.wait(). I've messed around with Timers, all of which I can't get to work

Comment: Is this a winforms app? If so, have you explored the BackgroundWorker? Kick off the backgroundworker and then display the form. Wire up the backgroudworker complete event to hide the form (along with processing the results from the server call.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean by to Show a form that required to close to make the others form can be use, just PleaseWaitForm.showDialog():